# access android core features questions

Tags: android, android-actionbar, attr

I am new to `android` development, and I encountered different cases when accessing the `android` core features, e.g.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

and

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

So what is the differences between `@` and '?' when accessing the `android` features/properties?

Another question is that it seems that I can't specify `?attr/actionBarSize` in `diemns.xml` and use it as a value in `layout` files,e.g.

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="activity_action_bar_overlay_margin">?attr/actionBarSize</dimen>
</resources>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_action_bar_overlay_margin" >
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```